# Reaching running application in minikube at 'localhost' on Linux

Tags: docker, kubernetes, localhost, minikube, nginx-ingress

I use `--driver=docker` and `minikube tunnel` in Windows (WSL2 and native) and macOS (Intel and M1) which makes the app running in the minikube cluster accessible in browser at `localhost` after applying `ingress-nginx`.

To make things consistent across Linux, macOS and Windows for a list of reasons that really aren't relevant to the question, I'd like to do the same in Linux (Ubuntu/Pop!_OS in particular).

I know Docker works differently with networking in Linux than it does with macOS and Windows, which is likely what is causing the issue.

For macOS and Windows, I'd normally just use the following which works regardless if using Docker Desktop or not:

```
kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/controller-v0.44.0/deploy/static/provider/cloud/deploy.yaml
```

For Linux, I've tried three different things:

```
# the recommended method for minikube (which doesn't work in macOS nor WIndows if using --driver=docker)
minikube addons enable ingress

# Docker Desktop
kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/controller-v0.44.0/deploy/static/provider/cloud/deploy.yaml

# Bare Metal
kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/controller-v0.44.0/deploy/static/provider/baremetal/deploy.yaml
```

The results, whether using `minikube tunnel` or not in Linux, are the same: "**localhost** refused to connect."

So my question is, which may be a question for `ingress-nginx`, is there a way to get the combination of `minikube` and `ingress-nginx` to serve the application at `localhost` in Linux like it does for Windows and macOS?

If not, I guess I need to be revise my dev deployment scripts to make this exception, but would like to avoid that if possible.

Comment: You create the minikube with `driver=none` on linux too?

Comment: Just gave that a shot and get a `localhost:8080 was refused` trying to run any `kubectl` commands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After short investigation it seems to me there is a wide problem related to `minikube`, `--vm-driver=docker` and `ingress`. And it seems it affects all the platforms, not only your specific case.

There are 2 open issues on github related to this. Both are fresh and opened:

**1.** [Ingress on docker driver - minikube 1.16 - ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/10245)

**2.** [docker: Ingress not exposed on MacOS](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/7332)

Are you able to use another `--vm-driver`?